# Fail to Install the Apache Package in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am following the tutorial here and I am stuck at this [page](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/rhel/bring-your-own-system/configure-a-package-and-service/). I am trying to install the Apache package by putting the recipe: `package 'httpd'` in a file named `webserver.rb` and run the command `sudo chef-client --local-mode webserver.rb` but this is the result that I get:

[image]

I am wondering why this is so and what is the best way to debug it?

Comment: The STDERR from howmebrew seems clear, there's nothing named 'httpd' to install. The packages names are not the same on RHEL and Mac OS X. Try running the tutorial into a redhat virtual machine to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: I see, but I am following this tutorial which is meant to be done on my local machine without a server. Maybe there is something wrong with the [documentation](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/rhel/bring-your-own-system/configure-a-package-and-service/)?

Comment: Not this linked tutorial is aimed at Red hat, there's one for red hat, one for Ubuntu and one for Windows. There's none for Mac for now in the basic part,  there's one on the chef-dk part.

Comment: I see, so which documentation do you recommend for me to follow if I want to learn chef on my Mac?

Comment: Well, the start of the tutorial asks you on what you'll be working [here](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/rhel/), there's an option for a free virtual machine. If not, you'll have to adapt the tutorial to Mac specificity (find the correct package name, change some pathes). I'm not a Mac user so I can't tell if ubuntu or RedHat is the closest one

Comment: If you want to stay local the best option is to install vagrant and virtualbox so you'll have a VM on your own machine. There's the chef-dk bootstrap wich handle setting this up on your mac [here](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chefdk_bootstrap#mac-quickstart)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will do that now.